# AWS Lambda SSH to Non-AWS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to ssh to a non-AWS instance to push some files via Lambda. I see ssh from Lambda is possible but I can't see an example of ssh to a non-AWS instance. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't see a reason why you coudn't do it. This probably will require custom deployment package probably to bundle necessary libraries for that, such as Fabric for python.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather unusual to use SSH from an AWS Lambda function. SSH is normally used for humans to login to a Linux computer.

If your goal is to get files onto a computer that is somewhere on the Internet, a better architecture might be to put the files in Amazon S3 and then have the remote computer 'pull' the data from S3. This offers better security and is a more 'loosely coupled' architecture.

If you *do* need to copy files from via an AWS Lambda function, consider using **scp** instead. There is a Python library available: [scp · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/scp/)

Comment: the partner system cannot pull, I have to push via ssh only. The files are small so I don't wanna use the ETL tool and I don't wanna spin an EC2 instance just for this activity.

Comment: Some people use the Paraminko SSH library. Here's an example: [Scheduling SSH jobs using AWS Lambda | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scheduling-ssh-jobs-using-aws-lambda/)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to connect to the non-aws instance via SFTP. You would want a library based on your runtime that supports SFTP.

Is their an intrinsic need to have the files be stored on a remote instance?

- https://pypi.org/project/pysftp/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client